# GetAsyncKeyState() very CPU heavy? Am I using it correctly?

Tags: c++, winapi, loops

I am using GetAsyncKeyState() in a simple pong game of mine to check if the user has pressed the arrow keys. I read online that you need to use this function a certain way however I found out that it is very CPU heavy (using 50% of my CPU!). This was rather disconcerting, however, after some playing around I found out that if I added a `sleep(1);` then the CPU usage went down to 0% and everything still worked fine. There must be a better way of using this function or at least a better way of lowering CPU usage.

Any help here would be much appreciated!

My Code:

```
while(true)
{
    for(i = 8; i < 191; ++i)
    {
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767)
        {
            if(i == VK_LEFT)
                 // do stuff
            else if(i == VK_RIGHT)
                 // do stuff
            else if(i == VK_UP)
                 // do stuff
            else if(i == VK_DOWN)
                 // do stuff
        }
    }
    Sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: You could react to `WM_KEYDOWN`/`WM_KEYUP` messages in your Window Procedure rather than polling the whole keyboard state continually.

Comment: The `Sleep` is pretty much the solution for infinite loops. It lets your thread give up time early rather than trying to hog the CPU every chance you get. Of course when dealing with keystrokes a window message loop is always preferred.

Comment: @chris Using it cant be good coding practice though can it?

Comment: @Flyphe it isn't. If you use `GetMessage`, the OS will make sure your thread is woken up when something interesting happens and idles the rest of the time.

Comment: If you're going to stick with this design, you might as well remove the `for`/`switch` antipattern and just check explicitly for `if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT))`, etc. No point in checking the state of keys that you don't care about.

Comment: @duskwuff ahh true! I didnt know you could explicitly do that! +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that `GetAsyncKeyState` is CPU-heavy; it's that you're calling it all the time as quickly as you can. It's equivalent to saying that `i++` is CPU-heavy when you run it in an infinite loop.

You either should use `GetMessage` to wait until you actually have input, or if that's not good enough (because you perhaps also want to update some animation without waiting for a message), then you should pick some polling interval and use something like [`MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684242.aspx) (or create frequently recurring timer messages with [`SetTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906.aspx)).

Comment: Ahh ok. So I am approaching this the wrong way then. Rather than wait for input, I need to have an event of some kind trigger when a key is pressed. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @you are polling the key state which means the thread is going to be continuously hogging the cpu. If its event driven , it becomes more like interrupt driven that wouldn't hog the cpu.

Answer (score 1):

Anything your program repeats infinitely without some sort of message mechanism, user input or something that blocks program execution, will by default cause the program to use up all the available CPU resources.

Your original implementation of keyboard input handling was grossly inefficient. By blocking the execution flow with `Sleep` you have managed to overcome that problem, but in the cost of accuracy - if the user manages to press a key in less than 1ms your program will simply ignore it.

Instead of using `GetAsyncKeyState` for constantly checking the keys for presses, you can utilize `SetWindowsHookEx` to set a keyboard hook and directly intercept and handle keystrokes directly. [These](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [should](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1264/KeyBoard-Hooks) help.

Other options are to use DirectInput, external input handling libraries or wrappers.